# Java EE doesnt update the changes I make

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

It's probably some simple setting I cannot find but since yesterday my eclipse doesn't propagate the updates I do to the code of the servlet.

Only the source code doesn't get updated the JSP pages still get updated.

Someone has an idea what the problem can be.

-I've already created a new Glassfish server
-And I've been trying some random things like debug and updating the glassfish core

Comment: Try to check your `java build path` in project properties. Or try `clean` project and server where you run servlet